# how to retrieve values from 100 Textboxes using loop

Tags: .net, asp.net

Friends,

I Have a grid of 100 or more text boxes (HTML OR ASP.NET) each will be containing a text value of fixed length, need ALL of these passed back to the back end form for mass updating of the database..

I can do this by simple going through each of the controls .text property in code behind.

However that makes the code to big and ugly.

I was wondering if there is any why to go through each control using some controlled looping structure and retrieve data

i.e.

```
Private List<string> getdata()
{
  Private List<String> MyList = new List<string>();
    foreach (Textbox)control txbControl in ....// don't know what this will be
     {
       MyList.Add(txbControl.text);
     }
}
```

Please note that all of these textboxes have unique ID tag on the page i.e.

```
<tablr>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TxB_Customize1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<td/>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TxB_Customize2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<td/>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TxB_Customize3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

...
...
...

Sorry forgot to mention this, text boxes are grouped in columns and each textbox in a given column shares similar name i.e. "Txb_Customize" in the given instance.

So when retrieving the values I also need to know from where its coming from (may be textbox ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can do something like:

```
int index = 1;
while ( ( TextBox tb
  = FindControl (
      string.Concat ( "TxB_Customize", index.ToString ( ) ) as TextBox != null )
{
  MyList.Add ( tb.Text );
  index++;
}
```

This could be good if you have actually some other textboxes as well, which is not part of this array of data.

Answer (score 8):

Look at the [`Control.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls.aspx) property.

You'd want something like:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
    // Ignore non-textboxes
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        list.Add(textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

If you're using .NET 3.5 you could do this in a simpler way with LINQ:

```
return Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
               .Select(textBox => textBox.Text)
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in javascript - give them one class name and get them all into a collection and loop through the collection and then simply post the values using ajax. JQuery can be very handy here -

$(".yourclassname").each(function(index){
$(this).val() //this will be the value of your textbox
})

you can coin one big string and parse on the server side or you can build a name value array and then use that instead

Comment: Hey Bharani

i am not so femilier with JQuery however i like it because i any way have huge amount of java script on the page.

can you please explain the "(index)" part in your answer. i.e. how do i get it. or its just a place holder.

i have figured out rest.

Thanks

Comment: each function is like a for loop and the index of the collection being iterated is passed as a parameter to the callback function. If inside the callback you need the actual DOM element you can use this or you can use $(this) if you need the jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the container's controls (with MyContainer.Controls), if all you have in there is text boxes it will be easy, otherwise you might need to do:

```
foreach (Control myBox in MyContainer.Controls)
{
    TextBox myBox = Control As TextBox
    if (myBox != null)
        // Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the logic of the code is related to textboxes'name, the only solution I see is to rewrite this code from scratch, then buy some good design books to the programmer who has written this crap.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to depend on server controls you can use the Request.Form collection.

However you will need to use the control ids to tell whether it is a text box, using the question's ids:

```
Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(n => n.StartsWith("TxB_Customize"))
                    .Select(n => new[] { n, Request.Form[n] });
```

Which returns a collection of {Id,Value} pairs.

Comment: Wouldn't n be the UniqueID? In that case n.StartsWith wouldn't work.

Comment: UniqueID: of course. Would need something a little more sophisticated to match the keys.